# CSS - Bring custom tabs to front

Tags: html, css

I am writing custom tabs using HTML and CSS only, and I have come up with this so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/ae4j8/

`index.html`:

```
...
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Loans</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

`index.css`:

```
ul { margin-top: 10px;}
ul li {
   border-bottom: 28px solid #3f3f3f;
   border-left: 28px solid transparent;
   border-right: 28px solid transparent;
   height: 0;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 -35px 0 0;
   padding: 0;
}
ul li:hover { border-bottom: 28px solid #7f7f7f; }
ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I want the first tab to appear infront of the second one and the second one infront of the third one.

Currently its first tab behind second tab behind third tab,which looks like the top-most tab.

Any ideas on how I can get the tabs reversed?

Comment: You can use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). Note that it only applies to **positioned** elements.

Comment: You could put the links in reversed order in your HTML and add `float: right` to your `li`. http://jsfiddle.net/ae4j8/4/

Comment: @Aniket [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ae4j8/9/) using `z-index`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, you could put your links in reversed order (so your 'first' link 'Products' gets rendered last and therefore on top of the other ones.) To put them with CSS back in the original order you use `float: right`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ae4j8/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add for `li` `position:relative` and `z-index:0`. And for `:hover` - `z-index:20`:

**CSS:**

```
ul li {
   ...
 position:relative;
 z-index:0;
}
ul li:hover { border-bottom: 28px solid #7f7f7f;z-index:1; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ae4j8/8/

I think it will be better